# R testthat not reporting failures or errors

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I am finding some weird results using `testthat`. When running `test_file`, individual `test_that` calls are discovered but there is no output to the console other than the name of the context and the returned `data.frame` does not have the expected results. I suspect I am doing something really dumb but have tried lots of alternatives and get the same outcome.

Here is my `tests.r` file:

```
context("The context")

test_that('should pass',function(){
    expect_equal(42,42)
})

test_that('should fail',function(){
    expect_equal(43,42)
})

test_that('should error',function(){
    stop()
})
```

I run `test_file` on it:

```
> require(testthat)
Loading required package: testthat
> test_file('tests.r')
The context : 

> results <- test_file('tests.r')
The context : 

> results
     file     context         test nb failed error user system  real
1 tests.r The context  should pass  0      0 FALSE    0      0 0.002
2 tests.r The context  should fail  0      0 FALSE    0      0 0.001
3 tests.r The context should error  0      0 FALSE    0      0 0.001
```

As you can see, no console output and in the results `data.frame` instead of having one failed test and one with an error it looks as though everything has passed.

When I run the function bodies directly in the console I get what is expected:

```
> expect_equal(42,42)
> expect_equal(43,42)
Error: 43 not equal to 42
Mean relative difference: 0.02380952
> stop()
Error:
```

This is what I am running:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_NZ.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_NZ.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_NZ.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_NZ.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_NZ.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_NZ.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_NZ.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] testthat_0.9.1
```

Suspecting that I may have a broken install or something I tried the same tests on Ubuntu Trusty/R 3.12 and Windows 7/R 3.11 and get the same results. I really must be doing something dumb!

When I write analogous tests using `Runit`:

```
test.should_pass <- function(){
    checkEquals(42,42)
}

test.should_fail <- function(){
    checkEquals(43,42)
}

test.should_error <- function(){
    stop()
}
```

I get the expected output and results:

```
> results <- runTestFile('tests.r')


Executing test function test.should_error  ... Timing stopped at: 0 0 0 
Error in func() : 
    done successfully.



Executing test function test.should_fail  ... Timing stopped at: 0 0 0.001 
Error in checkEquals(43, 42) : Mean relative difference: 0.02325581
done successfully.



Executing test function test.should_pass  ...  done successfully.

> results
Number of test functions: 3 
Number of errors: 1 
Number of failures: 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You define functions, but you do not call them. To call a function, use `what_is_the_meaning()`. In your third example, you have an anonymous function declaration, but again, you do not run it. By the way, `testthat` has functions like `expect_error`, check these out.

Comment: Thanks @tonytonov. I have edited my question so it has no allusions to Douglas Adams but is at least syntactically correct. Still, I get the same outcomes. Its very odd.

Comment: Don't forget to bring the towel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `testthat` tests you declare an *anonymous* function like so:

```
function() {
  expect_equal(43,42)
}
```

Run this piece of code. Is anything being actually executed? No, because you have given a declaration of function that you do not call. Now run

```
{expect_equal(43,42)}
```

This is a block of code, not a function.

Changing your test file to

```
context("The context")

test_that('should pass', {
  expect_equal(42,42)
})

test_that('should fail', {
  expect_equal(43,42)
})

test_that('should error', {
  stop()
})
```

yields

```
The context : .12


1. Failure(@test.R#8): should fail -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
43 not equal to 42
Mean relative difference: 0.02380952

2. Error: should error -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1: withCallingHandlers(eval(code, new_test_environment), error = capture_calls)
2: eval(code, new_test_environment)
3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
4: stop() at test.R:12
```

Comment: Of course! I knew I was doing something dumb. Or maybe its just that I've been writing too much Javascript lately - which is replete with the anonymous function pattern: `elem.click(function(){...`. Thanks a lot.